# How to diagnose specific SVN symptoms

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I began having SVN problems recently.  I have a project which is worked on by 2 developers.  I am one of them.

When I check something in, my partner can get my updates.  When my partner checks something in, and I update, I can not get any of her changes.

Do these symptoms sound familar to anyone?  How can I go about fixing them?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there her changes in her `svn log`?

Comment: @zerkms You mean for her to check her own svn logs?

Comment: @GeekedOut: I mean to perform `svn log` on both computers, her on yours.

Comment: The logs didn't show anything problematic.  Just recent checkins - all of them are there.

Comment: @GeekedOut: then everything is ok ;-) If you see that changes - you can `update` to them.

Comment: @zerkms No, I can see the log of the change.  But the changes do not get into my files.  My file system does not get updated with the changes - does that make sense?

Comment: @GeekedOut: it is not possible, I cannot believe. If you checkout to the empty directory - do you see that changes?

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely trust the Subversion service and would bet that your `svn update` is working fine.

First, I would verify that the other developer's `svn commit` was successful.  Just right click anywhere in Windows Explorer, select TortoiseSVN, & click Repo-browser.  You can type in your repository address here, and view the history of everything that was committed to that branch.  [Note: I'm assuming your client is Tortoise from the tag on this question.]

If you do see her commit listed in the Subversion logs, then make sure you are doing the update properly using this guide: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-update.html  **Any conflicts will require an `svn merge` operation!**

Also make sure you have the lastest TortoiseSVN, or you may be affected by this bug: http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#incompleteupdate

(And by the way, I like the format of the question "how would you diagnose...?")

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
svn --set-depth infinity <your-local-folder>
```

And then do an svn update.

Also, look here: http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#incompleteupdate

Update your TortoiseSVN and try with a new checkout.